# $\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|\langle x,w_i\rangle|$, $\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|\langle y,w_i\rangle|$ at same $w_i$ if $x$ and $y$ are close enough?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $|x|_2 = |y|_2 = 1$. Let $w_1, \ldots, w_N \in \mathbb{C}^n$.
Let $j,k \in \{1,\ldots, N\}$ such that
$$
|\langle x,w_j\rangle| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|\langle x,w_i\rangle|
\quad \text{and} \quad |\langle y,w_k\rangle| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|\langle y,w_i\rangle|.
$$
I think I should be able to force $w_j=w_k$ by assuming $|x-y|_2$ is small enough, but I'm having trouble justifying this.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: If $j$ is unique, you can deduce that $k = j$ for $y$ close enough to $x$ by continuity. If there are several maximising indices, $k$ can be any of them when $y$ is close to $x$, and which one it is depends on the direction of $y-x$.

Comment: You're right. But your comment about continuity let me do what I needed in my application. Thanks.